# Assign JSON data/response (api response) to itemsArray dynamically

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component

I am new to VueJs

“https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/blob/master/src/views/base/Tables.vue”

in above vue. I want to assign the data to “someData” variable dynamically. I tried to bind it like below but it doesn’t work.

`var someData = () => JSON.parse("[{‘Id’:2,‘RollNo’:1000,‘email’:‘test1@test.com’,‘status’:‘Inactive’},{‘Id’:3,‘RollNo’:1001,‘email’:‘test2@test.com’,‘status’:‘Active’}]");`

any suggestions please? how to bind it dynamically or through webapi using axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of struggle and searching all over the places; finally found the solution.

define an empty array and change from const to var to bind the data dynamically at later stage

```
var someData = () => [{}]
```

.
.
.

and inside export default { } call api in mounted method

```
mounted() {
    axios({ method: "GET", "url": "https://localhost:80/api/values" }).then(result => {
                  this.items = () => JSON.parse(result.data);

                }, error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.error= error;
                });
    }
```